# how I can get output after clicking submit button like Name saurav

Tags: vue.js

[code[][code 2[code 3][1]]][2]

please see this
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMpkG.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZoW2w.png

Comment: I have to use V-if and V-else please share same code.

Comment: someone please help me

Comment: someone p,ease help me

Comment: Please provide the code inline in your question without external reference.